# (PHP) If, Else not retrieve data in the condition properly

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I have a problem of If-Else condition here. As the codes below,

```
if($status == 'New'){
    $resultx0 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM application_data_file WHERE Position_ID = '".$pos_id."'  && Application_Status = 'New'  OR 'Received'  OR 'Checking' ");
}
elseif ($status == 'Not qualified'){
    $resultx0 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM application_data_file WHERE Position_ID = '".$pos_id."'  && Application_Status = 'Failed'  OR 'Not qualified' ");
}
elseif ($status == 'No Condition'){
    $resultx0 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM application_data_file WHERE Position_ID = '".$pos_id."' ");  
}
```

The "New" and "Not qualified" conditions are go for only the first one in "application_data_file" table. "New" condition will retrieve only "New" but no "Received" or "Checking" as I input in the condition and "Not qualified" condition will retrieve only "Failed" without "Not qualified".

I have no idea about this. Is there anything wrong in the conditions?

Cheers.

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the if-else. I think your problem is the WHERE clause in the SQL SELECT statement.  " `OR 'Received'` " evaluates to `OR 0`, which is equivalent to `OR FALSE`. The \`application_status\` column is being compared to a single value 'New'.  The rest of the statement ``OR 'Received' OR 'Checking'` is going to be discarded by MySQL, since that's equivalent to `OR FALSE OR FALSE`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM application_data_file 
             WHERE Position_ID = '".$pos_id."' 
             AND Application_Status IN ('New','Received','Checking')");
```

Answer (score 3):

your mysql syntax is incorrect

`Application_Status = 'New'  OR 'Received'  OR 'Checking'`

this should be

`Application_Status = 'New'  OR Application_Status = 'Received'  OR Application_Status = 'Checking'`

Or

`Application_Status IN ('New','Received','Checking')`

Answer (score 1):

The SQL statements are not being properly formed; in your case, I would suggest using IN to check the Application_Status field (like below);

```
$pos_id = mysql_real_escape_string($pos_id);

if($status == 'New') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM application_data_file"
            . " WHERE Position_ID='" . $pos_id . "'"
            . " AND Application_Status IN ('New', 'Received', 'Checking')";

} elseif ($status == 'Not qualified') {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM application_data_file"
            . " WHERE Position_ID='" . $pos_id . "'"
            . " AND Application_Status IN ('Failed', 'Not qualified')";

} else {
    // Includes the case where $status == 'No Condition'
    $query = "SELECT * FROM application_data_file"
            . " WHERE Position_ID='" . $pos_id . "'";

}

$resultx0 = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read the code carefully.

There are only two conditions in which we need to check position ids:

`New` and `Not qualified`. For `No Condition`, there is no check.

So, add only two conditions: `New` and `Not qualified`.

Take an array of position ids and if condition add `IN` clause, otherwise, no action.

```
// Initiate a blank array
$positionIds = array();
$status = 'New';
if ($status == 'New') {
    $positionIds[] = 'New';
    $positionIds[] = 'Received';
    $positionIds[] = 'Checking';
}
else if ($status == 'Not qualified') {
    $positionIds[] = 'Failed';
    $positionIds[] = 'Not qualified';
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM application_data_file WHERE Position_ID = '".$pos_id."";
if (! empty($positionIds)) {
    $comma_separated = implode("','", $positionIds);
    $comma_separated = "'".$comma_separated."'";
    $sql .= " AND Application_Status IN ( " . $comma_separated .  ")";
}
$resultx0 = mysql_query($sql);
```

> Please don't use mysql_* functions as they are deprecated and removed
>   completely in PHP 7 due to security reasons.

Comment: Application_Status's are strings

Comment: @Dagon, thank for the comment. I completely missed it. I have corrected my answer.